# HTML not render XMLDom which created by using TransformerFactory

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm working on a web project and am using XMLHttpRequest so I don't have to reload the page every time I send a request. The data returned will be an XMLreponseText

This is my function use to transform DomResult to XMLString

```
public static String parseDomToXMLString(DOMResult configPath, String xslPath) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Đã vào parse");
    StreamSource xslCate = new StreamSource(xslPath);
     DOMSource source=new DOMSource(configPath.getNode());

    //Mở string writter
    StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();


    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslCate);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"yes");
    transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));

    return writer.getBuffer().toString();//1 domresult mới sau khi apply stylesheet
}
```

I use the method is apply stylesheet so it can output the format I want
This is my stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:g="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/gundam"
exclude-result-prefixes="g"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="g:gundam">
    <div id="inside">
        <!--Nếu có hình thì mới show cái div-->
        <div style="width: 100%;background-color: whitesmoke;margin-top: 20px;height: max-content;padding: 5px">
            <!--Phần ảnh lớn-->
            <div style="width: 250px;height: 250px;background-color: pink;border: 2px solid black;display: inline-block">

                <img id="bigAvatar" src="" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>

            <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-left: 10px">
                <p id="gundamName" style="color: blue;font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//g:name/text()"/>
                </p>
                <p id="gundamType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//g:type/text()"/>
                </p>
                <p class="money" style="color: red;font-weight: bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//g:price/text()"/>
                </p>
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="{//g:detailLink/text()}" target="_blank" onclick="saveView('{//g:id/text()}','{//g:host/text()}')">
                    <p id="gundamLink">Go to shop page</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 20px;padding-bottom:  30px;">
                <!--Đây là chỗ hiện ảnh-->
                <xsl:for-each select="//g:picture">
                    <div style="background-color: green;height: 70px;width: 70px;display: inline-block;margin-left: 5px;border: 1px solid black">
                        <img id="smallAvatar" onclick="showBigAvatar('{text()}')" src="{text()}" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Method parseDomToXMLString will return me a string of xml and I return it to XMLHttpRequest via this function.

> response.getWriter().write(resultString);

This is my function i write in javascript to get a xmlString

```
        function saveClick(id, gundamtype, gundamhost, differ) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc;
        var url = "SaveClickAndViewServlet?id=" + id + "&interactionType=click" + "&gundamtype=" + gundamtype + "&gundamhost=" + gundamhost + "&differ=" + differ;

        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if (differ === "shop") {

                    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);//This is my result after request to server
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/xml");
                    var inside = xmlDoc.getElementById("inside");
                    var outside = document.getElementById("outsideDetail");

                    removeAllResultSearch(outside);
                    outside.appendChild(inside);
                }
            }
            ;
        }
        xmlHttp.send(null); //Bắt đầu gửi request đi
    }
```

My purpose is to convert that xmlstring into dom xml format and then mount it in the html to display it. But it doesn't accept html tags and only shows the result string

This is the result when I use this line

> outside.appendChild(inside);

to show up on my site

> PG 1/60 RX-0 UNICORN GUNDAM
>            PG
>            4200000
>            
>               Go to shop page ->

My website doesn't accept any html tags, and even if I write this question it doesn't get in the codesample section so I cant show to everyone, 
I can only take pictures so you can see them.[image: This the ouput string look like after a when i using method parseDomToXMLString]

And this is the result I get on my web
[image]

I run my web on Edge and Chrome, but none of them succeed. Please help me

Comment: Consider to set the `inneHTML` of the outside element to the `responseText` of the request you make. And use the ` html` output method in XSLT.

Comment: This is what i do like you said, i use html output in xslt, i change outside.appendChild(inside) to outside.innerHTML=inside. And the result in my web is only the text "[object Element]".

Comment: The suggestion is to set `outside.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText`.

Comment: It work, omg you are my life saver. Can you explain how it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Honnen's instructions, I was able to show the rendering interface. This is how i fix it.

In the function

```
      function saveClick(id, gundamtype, gundamhost, differ) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc;
    var url = "SaveClickAndViewServlet?id=" + id + "&interactionType=click" + "&gundamtype=" + gundamtype + "&gundamhost=" + gundamhost + "&differ=" + differ;

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (differ === "shop") {

                console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);//This is my result after request to server
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/xml");
                var inside = xmlDoc.getElementById("inside");
                var outside = document.getElementById("outsideDetail");

                removeAllResultSearch(outside);
                outside.appendChild(inside);
            }
        }
        ;
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null); //Bắt đầu gửi request đi
}
```

Change

> outside.appendChild(inside);

Into

> outside.innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

Comment: I would drop all the lines `xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlHttp.responseText, "text/xml");`, `var inside = xmlDoc.getElementById("inside");`, `removeAllResultSearch(outside);` as you don't need any XML parsing step if you want to insert HTML directly and setting `innerHTML` will overwrite any previous content of `outside`.

Comment: Ty, i will remove all those line.